# Data value not stored in variables (showing undefined)

Tags: javascript

I am not able to store the input in the variables after submitting my form.
It shows "undefined"
Here's the code:

````
var userInput1 = document.getElementById("inp1").value;
  var userInput2 = document.getElementById("inp2").value;
 var userInput3 = document.getElementById("inp3").value;
function king() {
document.write("Welcome " + userInput1)
return false;
}```
````

Comment: Are the elements you are getting the value an input type?

Comment: so.. yeah.. dumb question, is `userInput1` exists within the `king()` function context? have you tried to pass it as `parameter`?

Comment: Show us the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. It's fun to use JQuery too for shorter Syntaxes. (My example is pure JS)

```js
function fetch(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  
  //display
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Welcome "' + name + '" Your age is: "'+ age +'"';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<fieldset>
<legend>Sample</legend>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
  <br><br>
    <label>Age:</label>
  <input type="number" id="age"/>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="fetch()">Fetch Data</button>
</fieldset>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```